# Advises Going for an Oil and Gas conference as a Software Developer

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, conferences

I will be going for my visa Interview come March 6th this year, conference invitation though on Oil and gas, I have taken to memory the hotel, the address as well as the inviting party Invitation Information there in Texas.
I am believing By the grace of God I will make a headway, I have over 5 years of experience Working here in Nigeria, Not married.. Now here comes my question.

If I am going for a Conference would the visa officer ask me Questions Relating to the Conference? I am a Solutions Architect / Software Developer and I am going for an Oil and gas conference. We have built some Automated Projects for Some oil and gas companies too, and I stated it in my DS-160. Again, In the University, We did borrowed courses for Engineering and thats how I came to understand this course as well, Though not 100% , its a borrowed course - Remember.

What do you think, I am already studying about the Technology and Naval Architecture.
Advise needed.

Comment: IMHO they may ask why this particular conference is of interest to you, but I doubt they’ll spend time probing into its actual content. They are far more likely to focus on your ties to your home country and any hint that you may have immigrant intent.

Comment: It's not clear whether you are going to that conference because it's actually something relevant for your work or career, or for some other reason? Who is paying for the trip (flights, hotel, meals...)? What is your actual intention?

Comment: You say you "have taken to memory the hotel" etc. The more documentation you have with you the better, such as a reservation, and not rely on memory.

Comment: If the conference schedule / agenda has been published, you should write out which sessions you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

They will almost certainly ask you questions about the conference, because you say that is the reason you're travelling. They'll probably want to know why you're going and what you intend to do there. Are you giving a presentation? If so, what is it about?

Just tell them the truth and be confident. Remember that you know much more about the conference than they do: they're visa officers, not software developers or experts in the oil and gas industry. Because it's an oil and gas conference, they might ask you questions about oil and gas. It shouldn't matter if you don't know the answers, as long as you can explain why you don't know. And you can explain that: you're a software developer, not an expert on oil and gas.

It's probably not a good idea to try to memorize answers to questions ahead of time. That will make it look like you've been told what to say, which makes it look like you're not telling the truth.